# Unexpected output using Multicast Delegates in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Below is my code in C#, if you look at the attached output, the '**Removing Spaces**' method is invoked but the output does not really remove the spaces in the sentence, i cant figure out why? Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks !

[image: Program Output]

```
//using delegates for multicasting
using System;

//declare a delegate type
delegate void StrMod(ref string str);

class StringFunctions
{
static void ReplaceSpaces(ref string str)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Replacing");
    str = str.Replace(' ', '-');
}

static void RemoveSpaces(ref string a)
{
    string temp = "";

    Console.WriteLine("Removing spaces");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        if (a[i] != ' ') temp += a[i];

    a = temp;
}

static void Reverse(ref string str)
{
    string temp = "";

    Console.WriteLine("Reversing");
    for (int j = 0, i = str.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--, j++)
        temp += str[i];

    str = temp;
}


public static void Main()
{
    //construct the delegates
    StrMod strOp;
    StrMod replace = ReplaceSpaces;
    StrMod remove = RemoveSpaces;
    StrMod reverse = Reverse;

    string str = "this is a test";

    //setting the multicast
    strOp = replace;
    strOp += reverse;

    //invoke the multicast
    strOp(ref str);
    Console.WriteLine("Resultant string : " + str);
    Console.WriteLine();

    strOp -= reverse;
    strOp += remove;

    str = "This is a test"; //reset

    strOp(ref str);
    Console.WriteLine("Resultant string : " + str);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

}
```

Comment: I can't see any space in that output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your final operation you call both `ReplaceSpaces` and `RemoveSpaces` with your multicast delegate. `ReplaceSpaces` is happening first so `RemoveSpaces` has no work to do.

Turn your "Remove Spaces" function in to a "Remove Dashes" function and it should work like you are expecting.

**EDIT**: One Gotcha you may need to be aware of, I don't think the order of execution is guaranteed in multicast delegates. If you are doing things that rely on previous delegates executing first the order of execution may change in unexpected ways as items are added and removed from the multicast delegate.

EDIT2: [Nevermind.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c.aspx) This is what I get for not double checking before posting.

Comment: Oops, that didn't strike me ! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Neville please see my update I just added. Doing multicast delegates that depend on execution order is just asking for trouble. The framework does not guarantee that `ReplaceSpaces` will always execute before `RemoveDashes`. It may always work fine in your testing but you update your .NET and suddenly the program behaves differently. That is the danger of relying on "Undefined Behavior", Microsoft can change the behavior at will.

Comment: @Neville Nevermind, Adding and removing delegates (if using `Delegate.Combine` which is what `+=` uses internally) is well defined and will preserve order.

Comment: thanks once again for the advise ! Much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't remove any space because there is no space.You have changed all spaces with `-` before you call `RemoveSpaces` method.